# Где физически на компьютере хранится содержимое Idea - File - Procect Structure - Project Settings - Libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

1. Есть проект в Idea. Maven
2. Захожу в Idea - File - Project Structure - Libraries
3. Вижу такую картину:
   [image: Гляжу в настройки]
4. После этого я комментирую две зависимости с логированием.
   [image: Комментирую зависимости]
5. При этом в Libraries ничего не меняется.
6. Если же я жду Reload all maven project
   [image: Жму reload]
7. То библиотеки исчезают и из окна Maven
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
8. И из списка Libraries

**Вопрос:**
Где физически на компе хранится список, который мы видим в Idea - File - Procect Structure - Project Settings - Libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Чтобы понять суть, я создал пустой проект, который вообще не связан с Maven.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого я "руками" через Project Settings добавил то, что первое "попалось под руку".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Появился артефакт с указанием на физическое расположение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Показываю красным то, что физически меняется в Проекте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В терминологии Maven репозиторий – это каталог, в котором хранятся все файлы проекта, библиотеки, плагины или любые другие специфичные для проекта артефакты, которые Maven может легко использовать.

Репозиторий Maven бывает трех типов. Следующая иллюстрация даст представление об этих трех типах:

- локальный
- центральный
- удаленный

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Локальный репозиторий Maven – это папка на вашем компьютере. Он создается при первом запуске любой команды maven. Когда вы запускаете сборку Maven, Maven автоматически загружает все jar-файлы зависимостей в локальный репозиторий. Это помогает избежать ссылок на зависимости, хранящиеся на удаленном компьютере, каждый раз, когда создается проект. Локальный репозиторий Maven по умолчанию создается Maven в каталоге% USER_HOME%

Центральный репозиторий Maven – это репозиторий, предоставленный сообществом Maven. Содержит большое количество часто используемых библиотек. Когда Maven не находит никакой зависимости в локальном хранилище, он начинает поиск в центральном хранилище, используя следующий URL – https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Иногда Maven также не находит упомянутой зависимости в центральном хранилище. Затем он останавливает процесс сборки и выводит сообщение об ошибке на консоль. Чтобы предотвратить такую ​​ситуацию, Maven предлагает концепцию удаленного репозитория , который является собственным настраиваемым репозиторием разработчика, содержащим необходимые библиотеки или другие файлы проекта.

Comment: Боюсь, вы не поняли вопрос

Comment: Человек использует Maven. Он спросил где храниться библиотеки, которые он использует в проекте. Я написал все возможные вариант того, где могут храниться библиотеки. Ответ на вопрос не зависит от используемой среды разработки

Comment: Почему он не понял вопроса? Что за бред.
C:\Users\%USER%\.m2\repository  - вот путь до репозитория, если это Windows.
Почему ответ Даниила не верен?

Comment: 1. Я изменил путь репозитория на "не диск C". Это к делу не относится, это просто для инфо. Ибо я накачал 20ГБ библиотек. Когда разбирался, понял, что это "из-за Maven"
2. Автор выше указал на физическое расположение библиотек Maven. Но это ведь не значит, что мы их все используем. Задача была именно найти упоминания использования. Причем без привязки к Maven. Ибо Maven это "надстройка" над управлением зависимостями. Собственно разобрался. Ответ ниже.

Comment: Упоминания использованных библиотек есть в pom.xml. В вашем же ответе, вы указываете, что библиотеки лежат в папке maven, а упоминаются в libraries>apache.xml Если бы это был maven проект, то это было указанно в pom.xml Кроме того, в вопросе было сказано где физически хранятся библиотеки, а не где они упоминаются в проекте

Comment: Вопрос про список, который показывается в узле Dependencies. Не про сами файлы библиотк (которые видно на скрине в п. 3). Если бы вопрос был про файлы библиотек, то нет смысла показывать шаги 4-6. Если бы список в узле Dependencies отображал просто зависимости из pom, то как объяснить шаг 5? А объясняется он так, что этот список хранится отдельно и поэтому на шаге 5 он неактуальный и требуется шаг 6. И вопрос в том где этот список (сам список, какие библиотеки подключены к проекту) хранится, если это не просто отображение pom.xml. Ответ автора, кстати, тоже не отвечает на поставленный вопрос.